# Can i use the views.py file to actually send emails?

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to create a contact form in Django that actually sends emails for real. Can i put all the email configs in the views.py file itself? I want to do that because i want only the legitimate owners of emails to actually send emails. I do not people to send me emails using their friends email.

Comment: You can put anything anywhere. I guess the question is whether you should. If the email configs were in a different file, why would that mean people would be able to send emails using their friend's email?

Comment: All of the YouTube tutorials did not cover that. How would you make it so that the forms authenticates the user before sending the email while keeping the email configs in a separate file (like settings.py)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes obviously you can, but make sure you have your email credentials stored in your `settings.py` file safely
What is ideal is to save your email credentials as environment variables
In your `settings.py` File

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "from@example.com"
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
# If you are using any other smtp host. 
# Search documentation for other smtp host name and port number
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "from@example.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD"
```

In your view that you want to use to send email
`views.py`

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def email_send_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       # Get email information via post request
       to_email = request.POST.get("to", "")
       subject = request.POST.get("subject", "")
       message = request.POST.get("message", "")
       if to_email and message:
           email = EmailMessage(subject=subject,body=body,to=[to])
           email.send()
       # Complete your view
       # ...
       return redirect("REDIRECT_VIEW")
```

If you want to send `html template` or `image` using email `Email Template` via your django app

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from YourProject.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
def email_send_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       # Get email information via post request
       to_email = request.POST.get("to", "")
       subject = request.POST.get("subject", "")
       message = request.POST.get("message", "")
       if to_email and message:
           # Gets HTML from template
           # Make sure in this case you have 
           # html template saved in your template directory
           html_message = render_to_string('template.html', 
                                          {'context': 'Special Message'})
           # Creates HTML Email
           email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, 
                                        from_email=EMAIL_HOST_USER, 
                                        to=[to])
           # Send Email
           email.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
           email.send()
       # Complete your view
       # ...
       return redirect("REDIRECT_VIEW")
```